# Extract text from a class in HTML using CSS language

Tags: python, html

I have the following html piece

```
    soup = <span class="posting-location go-to-posting">
                                Santa Gertrudes , 
                                <span> Tatuapé, São Paulo</span>
    </span>
```

I know that, to access the "Tatuapé, São Paulo", I can use

```
soup.select_one('span')
```

However, how do I select "Santa Gertrudes , "?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML you provided.

Then I navigate the soup using the spans. After I have the target element, I get the text of the element.

```py
soup.span.span.text
```

or

This finds all spans and selects the second one.

```py
soup.find_all('span')[1]
```

I have this additional code before calling either of those.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = "<span class="posting-location go-to-posting">Santa Gertrudes , <span> Tatuapé, São Paulo</span></span>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for weeks, you just saved my job! I'll probably hold off until Friday to implement.

Comment: @JacobEvans I'm glad you found this useful!